# Angular 4 *ngFor limits and onclick event show more

Tags: angular

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes | slice:0:10;">
       {{ hero.name }}
   </li>
</ul>
<p *ngIf="heroes.length > 10" (click)="showMore()">show more 10</p>
```

I want show  more hero name on click.. also need to show how many hero name left.

Comment: you want server side pagination ?

Comment: no i do not want pagination. i want to show more name on click event.

Comment: It's not clear what is unclear for you. Please, add some notes of what you expect us to help you with

Answer (score 0):

`heroes` here is an array.
The `ngFor` statement you have written will show all elements of that array since you are not restricting the total number of elements shown.

If you are using the `heroes` array as a temporary array to contain only the elements which you are showing on screen, the `showMore()` function can be written like this:

```
showMore(){
    this.heroes.push(//put one of the elements you want to add to the array here)
    //you can use this line inside a forloop to add as many elements/heroes as you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfw7tu

I would just add

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let hero of heroes; let ndx = index">
  <li *ngIf="ndx >= 10">{{ hero.name }}</li>
</ng-container>
```

So you get something like

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes | slice:0:10">
       {{ hero.name }}
   </li>
   <ng-container *ngIf="showMore">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let hero of heroes; let ndx = index">
         <li *ngIf="ndx >= 10">{{ hero.name }}</li>
      </ng-container>
   </ng-container>
</ul>

<button (click)="showMore = true">Show more</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable using slice pipe, so, if your variable is called "page" and take the values: 0,1,2,3,...,heroes.lenght/10

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes | slice:page*10:(page+1)*10;">
       {{ hero.name }}
   </li>
</ul>
<p *ngIf="(page+1)*10<heroes.length" (click)="page=page+1">show more 10</p>

//in your component.ts
page:number=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution without using slice, example will show 10 entries by default, view more & view less buttons.

showMore: boolean;

```
 <div *ngFor="let hero of heroes; let i = index">
   <div *ngIf="i < 10 || showMore">{{hero.name}}</div>
 </div>
 <a *ngIf="!showMore" (click)="showMore = true">Show More {{heroes.length - 10}}</a>
 <a *ngIf="showMore" (click)="showMore = false">Show Less</a>
```